# Как увеличить шрифт текста при клике на кнопку на чистом js

Tags: javascript

Имеется счетчик, при клике на кнопку увеличивается число, нужно что бы еще увеличивался размер шрифта при каждом клике, вопрос что не так и как поправить

```js
window.onload = initializer;
var  theCount = 0;
function initializer() {
    document.getElementById("incremenButon").onclick = increaseCount;
    document.getElementById("incremenButon").addEventListener('click',changeSize);
}
function increaseCount() {
    theCount++;
    document.getElementById("currentCount").innerHTML = theCount;
}

function changeSize (e) {
    document.getElementById("currentCount").style.fontSize = theCount;
}
```

```html
<body>
    <h1>
        Щелкние на кнопке
    </h1>
    <p>
        Текущее зачение: <span id="currentCount">0</span>
    </p>
    <button id="incremenButon">
        Инкрементировать счетчик
    </button>

</body>
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

fontSize укажите в пикселях (em, rem), в чем надо, тогда заработает, например

```
document.getElementById("currentCount").style.fontSize = theCount + 'px'
```

Answer (score 1):

Можно так

```js
var  theCount = 0;
document.getElementById("incremenButon").addEventListener('click',changeSize);


function changeSize (e) {
    theCount++;
    document.getElementById("currentCount").innerHTML = theCount;    
    document.getElementById("currentCount").setAttribute('style', `font-size: ${theCount}pt`);
    
}
```

```html
<body>
    <h1>
        Щелкние на кнопке
    </h1>
    <p>
        Текущее зачение: <span id="currentCount">0</span>
    </p>
    <button id="incremenButon">
        Инкрементировать счетчик
    </button>

</body>
```